# Angular PrimeNG: How can check the status of the paginator?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a PrimeNG table.

Like the one in the examples.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/page

Is there a way I can see what page is selected in the paginator?
Or at least get an event of changing the page without doing it manually?

Think thats a basic requirement but I can not find anything in the Docs.

Comment: Read the full docs on the primeng table: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table. Everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

I found the binding to first (number of first record per page). Should do the job for me :-)

```
<p-table [value]="logs" [paginator]="true" [rows]="30" [(first)]="first">
```